# can't connect to mssql if the computer is using dhcp

Tags: sql-server, connection

In a small office I manage suddenly many pcs where unable to use an accounting program. This program is installed on a Windows 2012 server and on the pcs are installed client program which connect to this program. The program uses Microsoft Sql Server Express and I found out that the clients where no more capable of connecting to Sql Server.
After several attemptes I tried to change the network configuration of the clients from dhcp to static ip and this solved the issue. Even on a Mac with OS X El Capitan, on which the client program was installed through Parallels, I had to change the network configuration of the Mac.
Can someone explain how/why the dhcp can cause such an issue?

Comment: compare the actual network config from DHCP with the one you configure manually.

Comment: I used exactly the same parameters that where assigned by the DHCP.